# Creating a formula in Excel

Tags: excel

Can anyone please assist me.  On the attached screenshot, I need to know if the color of the cells B, E & F is green.

What formula should I use using the Name Manager functions?

Comment: I think you forgot to include the screenshot, you can paste it on imgur and add a link here if you don't have enough rep to post an image.  But I already can tell you there is no built in function that tells you the color of the cell.  You will need VBA to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Sheet1 and Row2, you may create a function in Name Manager by selecting say J2 and there creating a name, say GetColour which refers to:

```
=GET.CELL(63,Sheet1!B2)
```

Then in J2 copied across to N2:

```
=GetColour
```

and in, say, O2:

```
  =IF(AND(J2=10,M2=10,N2=10),"Green","Not all green")
```

though you may have to adjust the colour index to suit (ie something other than `10`) and you will have to refresh the sheet (Ctrl+Alt+F9) to see updated results.

This approach is not recommended and turning the cells green according to some rule is preferred. Whatever the rule is would then be used to determine whether all three cells meet it.